# How was this inequality derived?

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I am solving a functional equation and there was a step in the solution where they derived an inequality. It's this:
If $m > l$ where $m$ and $l$ are natural numbers then choose a natural number $n$ such that
$$n>\frac{l}{m-l}.$$

Thus we get the inequality
$$\left(\frac{m}{l}\right)^n =\left(1+\frac{m-l}{l}\right)^n>1+n\left(\frac{m-l}{l}\right).$$

So how was the inequality derived?

Comment: This is the bernoulli inequality which states that $(1+x)^n\geq 1+nx $ for $\geq 2$

Comment: There are some typos. I think you wanted to say $m >l$ and $n$ is chosen so that $ n >\frac l {m-l}$

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that $m>l$, we know that:

$$\frac{l}{m-l}>0$$

and so Bernoulli's inequality applies, which states:

$$(1+x)^n\geq1+nx$$

Setting the top equation as $x$ gives your result directly. We can prove Bernoulli's inequality by first saying $(1+x)^0\geq1,\forall{x}>0$. Let our induction hypothesis be:

$$(1+x)^k\geq1+kx$$

Which we will prove by proving the following:

$$(1+x)^{k+1}\geq1+(k+1)x$$

This can be easily done by:

$$(1+x)^{k+1}=(1+x)^k(1+x)$$
$$(1+x)^{k+1}\geq(1+kx)(1+x)$$
$$(1+kx)(1+x)=1+(k+1)x+kx^2$$
$$1+(k+1)x+kx^2\geq1+(k+1)x$$

Proving by induction that:

$$(1+x)^n\geq1+nx$$

Comment: Thank you, I don't know why this wasn't explained in the solution, they didn't even mention Bernoulli's inequality.